# Field keeps old value after update

Tags: vue.js

I have a form which is saved using ajax after each change in one of the fields.
The response from the ajax request is used to update some data in that instance but does not update the data that is used in my form.

The problem is when i change one of the fields, switch fast to the next field and start typing, it changes back to the value that it had before the ajax call after the request is done.

Code sample:

```
var vueCheckout = new Vue({
    el: document.getElementById('vue-container'),
    data: {
        billing_address: {
            'postcode' : '',
            'city' : ''
        },
        shipping_address: {
            'postcode' : '',
            'city' : ''
        }
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.billing_address = {postcode: 'postcode', city: 'city'};
        this.shipping_address = {postcode: '2', city: '2'};
    },

    methods: {
        changeAddress: function(type, key, event) {
            this[type][key] = event.target.value;

            var $this = this;

            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.shipping_address = {postcode: '3', city: '3'};
            }, 1000);
        },
    }
});
```

```
<div id="vue-container">
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="billing[postcode]" :value="billing_address.postcode" @change="changeAddress('billing_address','postcode',$event)" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" name="billing[city]" :value="billing_address.city" @change="changeAddress('billing_address','city',$event)">
    </div>
    <div>
    <span>{{ shipping_address.postcode }}</span> - <span>{{ shipping_address.city }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to reproduce:
https://jsfiddle.net/3au4m5qw/1/

Try changing the value of postcode and then switch fast to the next field (city) and change the value to something else.
You will see that the value is back to the original.

EDIT: jsfiddle with v-model.lazy: https://jsfiddle.net/hym63pL7/

Comment: If you want to resolve that, the easiest way would be to disable the inputs until the request returns. Another possibility would be to not update the form again but only to send the current state the back-end on a change.

Comment: Hi @ssc-hrep3, it's a must that i update the form. If i don't find another solution i will use the one you mentioned and i will disable the inputs if a request is in progress. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
v-model="billing_address.city"
```

instead of `:value`. V-model is two way binding and fixes your issue.

Comment: I have checked and it works with v-model, but with v-model.lazy it doesn't work (https://jsfiddle.net/hym63pL7/). Do you think it's possible to make it work with v-model.lazy as well?

Comment: This should be marked as answer since it answers OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think even changing to `v-model` the data from the ajax request won't be displayed because the data values will change but they won't be rendered. You need to wait until the DOM is updated using `nextTick`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick

```js
var vueCheckout = new Vue({
    el: document.getElementById('vue-container'),
    data: {
        billing_address: {
            'postcode' : '',
            'city' : ''
        },
        shipping_address: {
            'postcode' : '',
            'city' : ''
        }
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.billing_address = {postcode: 'postcode', city: 'city'};
        this.shipping_address = {postcode: '2', city: '2'};
    },

    methods: {
        changeAddress: function(type, key, event) {
            this[type][key] = event.target.value;

            var $this = this;

            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.$nextTick(function() {
                  $this.shipping_address = {postcode: '3', city: '3'};
                })
            }, 1000);
        },
    }
});
```

Similar issue here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-20-data-gotten-from-backend-via-ajax-can-not-be-shown-in-view